# Как поставить хук, на глобальное события движения мыши?

Tags: winapi, c#, .net, visual-studio

Как с помощью WinApi постоянно отлавливать события мыши? То есть я вожу мышью, по всему рабочем столу, а не только над формой и на форме постоянно меняются мышиные координаты.

Comment: C#, имхо, не для этого. Используйте Delphi в таком случае, что ли....

Answer (score 3):

Используя `WH_MOUSE_LL` хук, создав и зарегистрировав соответствующий обработчик. [Пример](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804/en-us).

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос не совсем корректный.

"Постоянно отлавливать события мыши" и "по всему рабочем столу" - это не "то есть",
это разные вещи.

"Постоянно", значит нужно ставить хук,

А "по всему рабочему столу" - достаточно вызвать **`SetCapture`**, это будет перенаправлять все сообщения мыши в окно до вызова **`ReleaseCapture`**, или до тех пор, пока кто-нибудь другой не вызовет **`SetCapture`** из другого окна, что сгенерирует в текущем - **`WM_CAPTURECHANGED`**.

Comment: Из всех ответов на детский вопрос этот несет хоть какую-то интересную инофрмацию. Ставлю +

Answer (score 1):

> я вожу мышью, по всему рабочем столу, а не только над формой и на форме постоянно меняются мышиные координаты.

Для этого в своем приложении запускаете таймер и каждые, например, 100 ms читаете координату мыши.

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

var frm = new Form() { Width = 400, Height = 100, TopMost = true };
var lbl = new Label() { Parent = frm, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 100, Enabled = true }
    .Tick += (s, e) => {
        var pos = Cursor.Position;
        lbl.Text = pos.ToString();
    };
frm.ShowDialog();
```

---

Информацию об окне под курсором мыши можно получить через вызовы Win API функций. Пример на C# в ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836).

Answer (score 0):

Хуки [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(v=VS.85).aspx)

Обычно такое в малваре используют, точнее в кейлоггерах. Но следует сразу сказать что виньапи для этих целей не пригодно :)

Comment: Это используют не только в троянах.

Answer (score 0):

Вот хорошая обёртка для C#: [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).