# Как получить информацию о Windows окне под курсором мыши?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, interop

Как получить информацию о любом из окон Windows, которое находится под курсором мыши?
Надо реализовать часть возможностей, которые есть в утилите Microsoft Spyxx.exe и выводить следующую иформацию:

- HWND,
- Class Name,
- [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx),
- RGB цвет пикселя,
- размеры окна.

Как получить координату мыши за пределами WinForms Application?
Как получить необходимую информацию об окнах и вывести, например, в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Для создания такого приложения надо использовать [Win API функции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919) для работы с окнами Windows.
Позиция курсора определяется по таймеру.

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
```

---

```
// Win API functions
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point p);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder cName, int maxCount);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT {
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetClientRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);
static public Color GetPixelColor(Point point) {
    var hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    var p = GetPixel(hdc, point.X, point.Y);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    return Color.FromArgb((int)(p & 0x000000FF),
                          (int)(p & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                          (int)(p & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
}
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HandleRef hWnd, out int processId);
```

---

```
class WindowStyles {
    static KeyValuePair<int, string>[] enums;
    static WindowStyles() {
        // читаем значения полей WS_* из internal class NativeMethods.
        var t = typeof(Form).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods");
        var b = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public; 
        enums = t.GetFields(b)
                 .Where(fi => fi.Name.StartsWith("WS_"))
                 .Select(fi =>
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)fi.GetValue(null), fi.Name))
                 .ToArray();
    }
    static public string[] ReadStyles(HandleRef hr) {
        var v = GetWindowLong(hr, -16);      // GWL_STYLE
        var res = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < enums.Length; i++) {
            var wsi = enums[i];
            if ((v & wsi.Key) == wsi.Key) res.Add(wsi.Value);
        }
        return res.ToArray();
    }
}
```

---

```
class HWndSpy {
    Timer Timer;
    public HWndSpy() {
        this.Timer = new Timer() { Interval = 500, Enabled = true };
        this.Timer.Tick += (s, e) => {
            this.Point = Cursor.Position;       // WinAPI: GetCursorPos
            this.HWnd = WindowFromPoint(this.Point);
            var hr = new HandleRef(this, this.HWnd);
            var cn = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetClassName(hr, cn, cn.Capacity);
            this.ClassName = cn.ToString();
            this.Styles = WindowStyles.ReadStyles(hr);
            var r = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(hr, out r);
            this.WindowRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom);
            GetClientRect(hr, out r);
            this.ClientRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom);
            this.Color = GetPixelColor(this.Point);
            int pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hr, out pid);
            this.ProcessId = pid;
            this.Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
    }
    public IntPtr HWnd { get; private set; }
    public String ClassName { get; private set; }
    public String[] Styles { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle WindowRect { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle ClientRect { get; private set; }
    public Point Point { get; private set; }
    public Color Color { get; private set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler Changed = delegate { };
}
```

---

```
var frm = new Form() { Width = 570, Height = 170, TopMost = true };

Func<DockStyle, Label> label = (d) => new Label() {
    Parent = frm,
    Dock = d,
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft
};

var style = label(DockStyle.Fill);
var cname = label(DockStyle.Top);
var bounds = label(DockStyle.Top);
var hwnd = label(DockStyle.Top);
var ws = new HWndSpy();
ws.Changed += (s, e) => {
    hwnd.Text = "HWnd: " + ws.HWnd + " (ProcessID:" + ws.ProcessId + ")";
    bounds.Text = "WindowRect: " + ws.WindowRect
                + "; ClientRect: " + ws.ClientRect;
    cname.Text = "ClassName: " + ws.ClassName;
    style.Text = "Styles: " + String.Join("; ", ws.Styles);
    frm.Text = String.Concat(
                  "HWndSpy -- Point: ", ws.Point,
                  "; Color: ", ColorTranslator.ToHtml(ws.Color));
};
frm.ShowDialog();
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Comment: не понятно, это ответ или дополнение?

Comment: разделил на блоки. и переделал для компиляции в C# Interactive.

Comment: @Stack: Я бы предложил в качестве WindowStyles вот такой enum: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowStyles.html. С enum'ом как-то проще и правильнее.

Comment: @VladD _"С enum'ом как-то проще и правильнее"_ -- так и собирался, но ответ и так большой, поэтому сократил SLOC до минимума.