# Как получить адрес памяти, выделенной окну через HWND?

Tags: winapi

Исследую окно чужого приложения.
С помощью функции GetWindow() получаю HWND дочернего окна (компонента). Соответственно, раз это окно, то ему должна быть выделена память в процессе.
Вопрос заключается в следующем: как прочитать память, выделенную этому окну? и можно ли ее получить зная HWND? Читать память выделенную всему процессу уже научился. Другими словами, нужно в этой памяти найти кусок, принадлежащий окну с хендлом HWND

Comment: А что за "память окна" такая? Изображение внутри окна или структуры данных, с ним связанные?

Comment: "Память под окно" может быть и в ядре и вообще где угодно...

Comment: Похоже, Вы микроскопом гвозди забиваете. Напишите что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Похоже Вы пытаетесь для себя разобраться, что накое Handle и какую информацию из него можно получить. Я бы вам посоветовать посмотреть для начала `GetUserObjectInformation`, а потом `NtQuerySystemInformation` с `SystemHandleInformation`  и `NtQueryObject` с `ObjectTypeInformation`. В любом случае, Вам нужно понять, что постановку вопроса нужно сменить. Знание IP адреса не дает Вам возможность посмотреть внутрь этого компьютера. Так и знание Handle не дает право копаться в кишках объекта с ним связанного. Есть много пректов, где люди дизассемблировали код User32.dll. Но нужно ли Вам это?

Comment: _"как прочитать память, выделенную этому окну?"_ -- наверное вам нужна информация об окне, его размеры, и т.д.; ее можно получить через WinAPI функции. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836)

Answer (score 2):

Похоже Вы пытаетесь для себя разобраться, что накое `Handle` и какую информацию из него можно получить. Я бы вам посоветовать посмотреть для начала [GetUserObjectInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683238(v=vs.85).aspx), а потом [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx) с `SystemHandleInformation` и [NtQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383(v=vs.85).aspx) с `ObjectTypeInformation` (см. [здесь](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html) примеры).

В любом случае, Вам нужно понять, что постановку вопроса нужно сменить. Знание IP адреса не дает Вам возможность посмотреть внутрь соответствующего компьютера. Так и знание `Handle` не дает право копаться в кишках объекта с ним связанного. Есть много пректов, где люди дизассемблировали код `User32.dll` (например Wine см. [здесь](https://www.winehq.org/) и [здесь](https://wiki.winehq.org/Git_Wine_Tutorial), [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) и др.). **Но нужно ли Вам это?**

Вообще говоря, `Handle` это примерно следующее. Вы пишите DLL и хотите предоставить удобный интерфейс использования. Для этого вам нужно аллокировать какие-либо объекты или сохранить кде-либо `Handles`, полученные от др. DLL. Тогда Вы сохраняете аллокированные объекты в таблицу (*внутреннюю в вашей DLL*) и возвращаете из вашей DLL индекс в этой вашей внутренней таблице вместо адреса аллокированного объекта. Такая схема имеет много преимуществ. Например, если Вы пишите не DLL, которую сагружают в свой процесс, а Exe, то идея с `Handles` работает тоже. Даже если мой процесс - это kernel mode драйвер, то все работает также. Имейте ввиду, что значение `Handles` может быть в общем случае что угодно: индекс в какой-лимо таблице, виртуальный адрес в памяти другого процесса, какое либо хэш значение и т.п.

Лет двадцать назад было круто покопаться во внутренних структурах Windows. [Undocumented Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201608340), [Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201721872), [Недокументированные возможности Windows NT (1998) А. В. Коберниченко](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33859555/) и т.п. Я много времени потратил в свое время на подобное чтиво и некоторые из этих книг я только-что нашел на своей книжной полке. Но поверьте мне, практической пользы от этих книг мало, особенно теперь. Я даже не помню когда я брал это книги с полки.

Если я Вас все же не убедил, то можете взглянуть [сюда](http://winterdom.com/dev/ui/wnd) (ищите `struct WND`) или [сюда](http://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/d79/include_2ntuser_8h_source.html) (ищите `typedef struct _WND`), [сюда](https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Techwiki:Win32k/WND) и т.д. Там описанна внутренняя структура `WND` которая мазо изменилась и первой публикации кажется в [Undocumented Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201608340).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Пожалуйста! Рад если смог чем-то помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Графический интерфейс в Windows построен на основе оконной подсистемы - Windows Manager, GDI и DWM. Прямой доступ к памяти этих подсистем обычными способами не получите. Посмотрите ниже на скриншот ядра ОС. Обратите внимание где находится ваше приложение, а где находится GDI.
Вместо прямого доступа к памяти этих подсистем, вы получаете дескриптор.

HWND - это дескриптор окна - как порядковый номер игрока в футбольной команде. Если надо получить информацию об окне, то HWND надо передать в одну из [оконных функций WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx), и Windows будет знать о каком окне вы спрашиваете и предоставит вам информацию, но не само окно.

Пример работы с оконными функциями WinAPI из кода на C# -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836).

Если надо получить дополнительную информацию о Windows, и надо менять системные функции, то для этого предназначена система [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Версия Express бесплатная и ее можно скачать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: [Архитектура Windows NT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_Windows_NT)

Comment: @Abyx _"При чем тут C#? Чтобы вызывать функции winapi надо использовать языки, которые для этого предназначены."_ -- посмотрите [исходники .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) -- они на C# и там очень много вызовов WinAPI

Comment: @Abyx _"тут не нужен перехват функции, достаточно использовать отладчик."_ -- а в каком отладчике можно посмотреть что происходит в графической подсистеме Windows? и, интересно, для чего это может понадобиться?

Answer (score 0):

Windows использует HANDLE как индекс в таблице. Как итог - вы получите кусочек памяти, который модифицируется стандартными WinAPI функциями. Т.е. функциями GetWindowPos EnumWindowProps GetWindowLong GetClassLong и другими из раздела справки. Думаю взлом windows - дело неблагодарное.
Так как я похожее что-то делал то советую:

1. Функций
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx и https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx вам хватит для получения нужной информации.

2.Из ссылок на память,
Используются обработчики класса и окон WindowProc, которую можна получить ф-цией GetClassLong и GetWindowLong.

3. Некоторые программы (delphi например) используют string-heх ccылки на память (адрес обьекта) в Window-properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
4. Некоторую информацию (например текст RICHEDIT MEMO, пароли и т.п.) можно получить с помощью ф-ции PostMessage / SendMessage.
5. Custom-классы могут использовать память, доступ к которой идёт SetClassLong(HWND, index >= 0 , value). Чаще всего в нулевой индекс заносят ссылку в памяти на "обьект" класса. Вобщем эти 4-ре функции (Get/Set Class/Window)  позволяют получать значение первичной оконной памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. собственно я понял - из HWND можно получить только информацию, предоставляемую функциями WinAPI (GetWindowLong и т.п.). Вообще мне нужно было получить значение некоторых полей окна, которые не относятся  стандартным. Похоже тут только дизассемблировать...

Comment: @MaluhinDenis _"мне нужно было получить значение некоторых полей окна, которые не относятся стандартным"_ -- какие поля не являются стандартными? если вам надо что-то менять в системе, то посмотрите Detours. ссылка в моем ответе.