# Как и когда нужно имплементировать IDisposable?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

В каком случае мой класс должен имплементировать интерфейс `IDisposable`? Подскажите правильную имплементацию. Что такое неуправляемые ресурсы, и как нужно оформлять их закрытие?

Comment: Обсуждение вопроса и ответа ведётся в этом чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34925/idisposable

Answer (score 89, accepted):

### А что это вообще?

Объекты в .NET уничтожаются по своим хитрым правилам. Не как в C++, где объект уничтожается как только выходит из области видимости. В .NET реализована *сборка мусора*: если на объект нет ссылок, то он считается никому не нужным, и его находит и съедает «сборщик мусора». Причём не сразу, а когда ему заблагорассудится, может даже вообще никогда. [На самом деле, если на объект есть ссылка, но из другого никому не нужного объекта, то эта ссылка как бы не считается.]

Например, если вы обнулите ссылку на объект, это не приведёт к его немедленному уничтожению, т. к. сборщик мусора может пробежать и позже. (Это вообще не обязательно приведёт к его уничтожению даже потом: на этот объект могут быть и другие ссылки.)

Это может приводить к неприятным эффектам. К примеру, если мы в C++ открыли файл в конструкторе объекта, то мы его можем закрыть в деструкторе. При этом мы точно знаем, когда файл будет закрыт: по окончанию блока, в котором объявлен объект. Если мы откроем файл в конструкторе класса C#, и попытаемся закрыть его в деструкторе, получится плохо: деструктор вызывается лишь тогда, когда сборщик мусора убирает объект, то есть, непонятно когда, и может быть даже вообще никогда. Это значит, что если мы в другой части программы попытаемся открыть снова этот же файл, нам это не удастся: файл может быть всё ещё открыт старым объектом.

Выходит, что деструктор в C# практически бесполезен, и применять его вам придётся очень редко. (Он, кстати, официально называется *финализатор*.)

Какой выход из этой ситуации? Выход есть, но он требует внимания.

Вы можете объявить метод, который можно вызывать, когда объект должен «умереть». Это делается при помощи интерфейса `IDisposable`, у которого есть один метод `Dispose()`. В этом методе и должна происходить «подчистка».

Но этот метод не будет вызван *автоматически*. Этот метод должны всё равно вызвать *вы*, система не сделает это за вас. Для системы `IDisposable` просто ещё один интерфейс, он не имеет никакого особого значения (например, деструктор про него вообще не в курсе). Есть ещё удобная конструкция `using`, которая вызовет для вас метод `Dispose` в конце блока:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.ReadLine());
}
```

это почти то же, что

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path);
Console.WriteLine(r.ReadLine());
r.Dispose();
```

(но правильно работает в случае исключений и тому подобных штук).

Зачем такой метод, если есть деструктор? Как мы уже выяснили, деструктор вызывается непонятно когда, или вообще никогда. Невозможно вызвать деструктор в подходящий момент. А вот вызвать метод, типа `Dispose`, в подходящий момент можно.

### Когда это нужно?

Начнём с простого примера. Пускай у вас есть в классе поле (ну или свойство), которое имплементирует `IDisposable`. В этом случае ваш класс тоже должен имплементировать `IDisposable`, чтобы во время своего `Dispose` вызвать `Dispose` и для внутреннего объекта.

Другой случай, когда вам практически всегда нужно реализовывать `IDisposable` — это если ваш класс работает с WinAPI, и имеет хэндл на внешний объект. Например, вы открываете файл через WinAPI, используя P/Invoke. В этом случае вам нужно вовремя закрыть его, и для этого реализовать `IDisposable`.

Давайте посмотрим, что это значит в общем случае. В нашем классе есть какая-то штука, за которую мы отвечаем, и которую должны прибить в конце существования класса. Такую штуку обычно называют *ресурсом*.

Ресурсы делятся на управляемые (те, которые являются по сути .NET-объектами) и неуправляемые (они обычно являются хэндлами системы и хранятся в `IntPtr`, но в принципе могут быть любым объектом вне данного рантайма .NET, или даже просто чисто логической сущностью, наподобие права на показ нотификации пользователю). Управляемый ресурс может *внутри* себя содержать и неуправляемые ресурсы.

Если ваш класс содержит ресурс (например, поле или свойство типа `IDisposable`, или неуправляемый объект WinAPI) вы (скорее всего) **должны реализовать `IDisposable`**. (Исключение — если ваш объект не *владеет* ресурсом, а держит ссылку на него «чтобы просто посмотреть». Другими словами, если за уничтожение ресурса отвечает кто-то другой.)

Закрытие управляемого ресурса практически всегда сводится к вызову `Dispose`, т. к. этот ресурс сам должен реализовывать `IDisposable`. Закрытие неуправляемого ресурса делается специфическим для типа этого ресурса образом.

Если вы пользуетесь неуправляемым ресурсом, превратите его в управляемый ресурс путём упаковки в `SafeHandle` (об этом ниже). [Разве что у вас есть **очень** веская причина так не делать. Нет, лень не считается веской причиной.]

Если вы храните ссылку на другие объекты в вашем классе, но эти объекты не имплементируют `IDisposable`, то вам скорее всего не нужно реализовывать `IDisposable` самому. **Память сама по себе не является ресурсом, который надо освобождать**: этим за вас занимается сборщик мусора. Раз вы не можете вызвать `Dispose` у подобъектов, то они будут освобождены, когда их «съест» сборщик мусора. Поскольку после `Dispose` ваш объект обычно больше никому не нужен, то он сам скоро будет недоступен, и ссылки из него на подобъекты не будут для сборщика мусора важны, так что обнуление ссылок ничего не даст.

То есть если ваши поля — обыкновенные объекты, не `IDisposable` (например, строки), то вам скорее всего **не нужно** реализовывать `IDisposable` для вашего класса. Если же какой-то один из ваших подобъектов реализует `IDisposable`, то и вам тоже скорее всего нужно реализовать `IDisposable`.

Реализация `IDisposable` для случая, когда в вашем классе есть как управляемые, так и неуправляемые ресурсы, сложна и содержит много тонких моментов. Поэтому Microsoft настоятельно рекомендует не пытаться сделать это, а обернуть неуправляемый ресурс в `SafeHandle` (или другой объект, чьё предназначение — обёртка для ресурса), и на уровне *вашего* класса работать лишь с управляемыми ресурсами.

### Как имплементировать `IDisposable` правильно?

Если у вас в классе есть неуправляемые ресурсы, сделайте для них управляемую обёртку, как рассказано ниже.

Для случая, когда у вашего класса нет потомков, вы должны просто в `Dispose` освободить ресурсы. В случае, когда клиент забудет вызвать `Dispose`, подобъекты вашего класса съест сборщик мусора, и у них (или их подобъектов) вызовется финализатор, который освободит ресурсы. Вашему классу финализатор в этом случае вовсе не нужен.

По конвенции, `Dispose` не должен бросать исключений при правильном применении, вы должны следовать этой конвенции, и можете рассчитывать на то, что правильно реализованный `Dispose` у ваших ресурсов тоже не бросает исключение тоже. (Если он таки бросает исключение, это баг, и имеет смысл сообщить автору кода о баге, а тем временем защититься при помощи `try`/`catch`.)

Вот примерный скелет имплементации (одолжен из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486322/10105)):

```
sealed class C : IDisposable
{
    SomeResource1 resource1;
    SomeResource2 resource2;
    // тут могут быть ещё ресурсы

    bool isDisposed = false;

    public C()
    {
        try
        {
            resource1 = AllocateResource1();
            resource2 = AllocateResource2();
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        // использовать удалённый объект -- ошибка, её лучше проверять
        if (isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Use called on disposed C");
        // ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // мы уже умерли? валим отсюда
        if (isDisposed)
            return; // Dispose имеет право быть вызван много раз

        // освободим ресурсы
        if (resource2 != null)
        {
            resource2.Dispose();
            resource2 = null;
        }

        if (resource1 != null)
        {
            resource1.Dispose();
            resource1 = null;
        }

        // и запомним, что мы уже умерли
        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Для чего нам try/catch в конструкторе? Если получение ресурса может окончиться неудачей или выбросить исключение, имеет смысл освободить ресурсы сразу, т. к. в этом случае `Dispose` клиентом вызвано не будет (он не получит ссылку на объект). В случае, если код в конструкторе гарантировано не может выбросить исключение, паттерн можно упростить:

```
sealed class C : IDisposable
{
    SomeResource1 resource1;
    SomeResource2 resource2;

    bool isDisposed = false;

    public C()
    {
        resource1 = AllocateResource1();
        resource2 = AllocateResource2();
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        // использовать удалённый объект -- ошибка, её лучше проверять
        if (isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Use called on disposed C");
        // ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;

        resource2.Dispose();
        resource1.Dispose();

        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Для случая иерархии классов метод `Dispose` в базовом классе нужно объявить виртуальным, и не забыть вызвать `base.Dispose()` в конце порождённых классов:

```
class C : IDisposable
{
    // ...
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;
        if (resource != null)
        {
            resource.Dispose();
            resource = null;
        }
        isDisposed = true;
    }
}

class C2 : C
{
    // ...
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;

        if (resource2 != null)
        {
            resource2.Dispose();
            resource2 = null;
        }

        base.Dispose();
        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Финализаторы и паттерн с `Dispose(bool disposing)`, рекомендуемый FxCop'ом, в этом случае не нужны, т. к. неуправляемых ресурсов наши классы не содержат. Так что предупреждение об этом можно игнорировать.

### Как создать управляемую обёртку?

Итак, у нас есть неуправляемый ресурс (то есть, ресурс, не сводимый к .NET-объекту). Нам нужно построить для него `IDisposable`-обёртку.

Для начала, если наш ресурс — хэндл, то скорее всего у вас уже есть определённый во фреймворке потомок `SafeHandle`, подходящий для вашего ресурса. Загляните в пространство имён [`Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.aspx). В частности, вы можете использовать

- [`SafeFileHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx), [`SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedfilehandle.aspx), [`SafePipeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safepipehandle.aspx) для файлов, отображений файлов в память и пайпов (каналов).
- [`SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedviewhandle.aspx) для представлений памяти.
- целая группа [`SafeNCryptKeyHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safencryptkeyhandle.aspx), [`SafeNCryptProviderHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safencryptproviderhandle.aspx), [`SafeNCryptSecretHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safencryptsecrethandle.aspx) для криптографических функций WinAPI.
- [`SafeRegistryHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.saferegistryhandle.aspx) для работы с реестром.
- [`SafeWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safewaithandle.aspx) для хэндлов, по которым можно ожидать чего-нибудь.

Эти классы представляют собой готовые обёртки, вы можете использовать их в определениях P/Invoke. Или если вам не совсем подходит один из готовых классов, вы можете унаследоваться от `SafeHandle` и получить свою обёртку. Пример [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482450/10105), демонстрирует обе техники:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

class FindHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private FindHandle() : base(true) { }
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle() { return FindClose(this); }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern bool FindClose(FindHandle handle);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct DATA // WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public FileAttributes FileAttributes;
    public FILETIME CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime;
    public uint FileSizeHigh, FileSizeLow;
    public uint Reserved0, Reserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string FileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string AlternateFileName;
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern FindHandle FindFirstFileEx(string name, int i, 
                                         out DATA data, int so, IntPtr sf, int f);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool FindNextFile(FindHandle h, out DATA data);
```

Если вам нужно создать собственную обёртку, а готовые базовые классы не подходят, подойдёт такой костяк:

```
class CustomResourceHolder : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr resource;
    bool isDisposed = false;

    public CustomResourceHolder()
    {
        resource = AllocateUnmanagedResource();

        // эта строчка нужна в конце конструктора, иначе финализатор может начать
        // есть объект до окончания работы конструктора!
        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    public IntPtr GetHandleDangerous() { return resource; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DoDispose();
        // эта строка гарантирует, что объект будет считаться достижимым
        // до конца DoDispose, и что в случае Dispose финализатор вызван не будет
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        // эта строчка обычно не нужна, но если вы что-то поменяете
        // в DoDispose, может стать нужна
        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    ~CustomResourceHolder()
    {
        DoDispose();
    }

    void DoDispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed) return; // идемпотентность Dispose

        // в любом случае освободим ресурс
        // нам нужна понадобиться проверка того, а был ли реально аллоцирован
        // ресурс (например, его выделение могло бросить исключение)
        if (resource реально был выделен)
            FreeUnmanagedResource(resource);

        // и запомним, что мы уже умерли -- это должно быть последней строкой
        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

---

*Подстрочное примечание для знатоков*: зачем нужен `GC.KeepAlive(this)` в конце конструктора? Нам нужно гарантировать, что финализатор не начнёт выполняться до окончания конструктора.
(Он может! См. [тут](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/) [раздел «*Myth: An object being finalized was fully constructed*»] и [тут](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/)).
Тело конструктора в реальном коде может быть сложнее, и гарантии, что последним в конструкторе будет обращение к `this`, а не работа с полученным ресурсом, достаточно сложно, и требует отдельных усилий. (Свою долю сложности привносит и оптимизатор, который может переставить куски кода.)

Использование `GC.KeepAlive(this)` в конце конструктора позволяет избавиться от этих проблем наиболее простым способом.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [Stephen Cleary, *IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation*](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)

---

Огромное спасибо @PashaPash, @Stack, @Discord, @Pavel Mayorov и @i-one, которые своей конструктивной критикой и рекомендациями очень помогли улучшить ответ.

Comment: _"неуправляемые (они обычно являются хэндлами системы и хранятся в IntPtr)"_ -- точнее: ресурсы неуправляемые, если они находятся/хранятся за пределами .NET-рантайма. например, дескриптор окна - это IntPtr, но само окно находится в оконной подсистеме Windows, см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485117/196972)

Comment: с классами `C` и `C2 : C` непонятно `isDisposed` один или у каждого свой.

Comment: @Stack: Угу, у каждого свой. Хотя в принципе это не принципиально, можно и общий protected.

Comment: @Stack: Да, или просто умозрительной конструкцией, типа «право показать рекламу» (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10316452/276994). (Это было к первому комментарию.)