# Различие Dispose , Finalize, Деструктора и класса GC

Tags: c#

Попытал счастья в гугле по этой теме и окончательно завис.

1. Начну с `GC` - ранее в Шилдте читал о том что нельзя вызывать сборщик мусора, что он запускается самой средой автоматически и с этим ничего не поделать, однако нашел такой вот метод `GC.Collect()` , который по описанию именно запускает сборщик мусора. А сам класс `GC` еще и позволяет им управлять. Так все-таки выходит , что его можно вызывать вручную ? Или есть какие-то тонкости и нюансы ?
2. Просветите в чем собственно разница между `Dispose и Finalize` ? Что из них работает с управляемыми , а что с неуправляемыми ресурсами ? И в чем суть реализации интерфейса `IDisposable` (ведь по сути все можно сделать в деструкторе) ? Насколько я понял, деструктор и `Dispose` делают одно и тоже. Если нет, то что тогда делает деструктор (ранее я читал что в деструкторе описываются шаги которые должна сделать программа при уничтожении объекта, но ведь и `Dispose` по сути делает то же самое).
3. Из всего вышенаписанного становится совсем не понятно, что делает тогда `Finalize`. Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: тут есть очень подробный ответ про Dispose и правила уничтожения объектов в .NET http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486697/198316

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Можно. Но редко бывает нужно.
2. У них вообще мало общего. Dispose нужен для освобождения ресурсов "здесь и сейчас" (не совсем так на самом деле. Вызов Dispose сигнализирует, что вы хотите освободить ресурс, но не факт, что это обязательно случится вот прямо тут же). Необходимость и преимущество интерфейса IDisposable именно в том, что его реализация позволяет освобождать ресурсы не тогда, когда до них доберется сборщик мусора, а тогда, когда это нужно программисту. Ресурсы могут быть дорогими, и держать их в памяти неопределенно долгое время может быть слишком расточительным. Деструкторов в C# нет вовсе. Есть финализаторы. Разница в том, что время вызова финализатора не определено. 
   Стоит также отметить, что если Dispose предназначен для вызова вручную, то финализатор вручную вызвать нельзя. Это делается автоматически.
3. Finalize выполняется перед уничтожением объекта. Можно сказать, что это  "последний шанс" освободить ресурсы корректно. Можно также считать, что Finalize - это "последняя воля умирающего" объекта. Определять этот метод имеет смысл только в случае, если класс имеет доступ к каким-либо неуправляемым ресурсам.

Comment: Выходит, что деструктор и финализатор это одно и то же ? А срабатывает ли конструкция `using` в объекте, где не реализовывают IDisposable ?

Comment: @PolyakovSergey русским же языком написал: нет, не одно и тоже. Даже написал, в чем разница. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: GС руками вообще лучше не трогать, без крайней необходимости.

Answer (score 5):

Следует еще помнить про то, что при явном определении метода Finalize, во время создания объекта в куче, CLR проверяет, содержет ли объект специальный метод Finalize и если да, то данный объект помечается как финализированный.

У CLR есть специальная внутренняя очередь – "очередь финацилизации", в которую кладется ссылка на финализируемый объект. По сути, на самом деле это просто таблица, которую сборщик мусора дергает, и получает по ней информацию по объектам, которые должны быть финализированы перед началом сборки мусора.

Если сборщик мусора планирует "прибрать" объект, который лежит в очереди финализации, сначала он копирует его в промежуточную таблицу финализации, а затем в отдельном потоке выполняет финализацию объектов из этой таблицы.

В результате процесс сборки состоит минимум из двух этапов, и содержит довольно большое кол-во действий, которые необходимо проделать, **что будет сказываться на производительности.**

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, в C# есть деструкторы и описывается он как метод, начинающийся со знака ~ и имеющий название класса. Своего рода конструктор, только наоборот и без модификаторов доступа и параметров.

```
~MyClass() { //Код деструктора }
```

Однако, если капнуть глубже, то оказывается, что деструктор является синтаксическим сахаром и компилятор "разворачивает" деструктор в следующую конструкцию, где идёт вызов метода Finalize класса Object:

```
protected override void Finalize() 
{
  try
  {
    //код деструктора
  }
  finally
  {
    base.Finalize();
  }
}
```

Суть реализации IDisposable: интерфейс IDisposable, в котором есть единственный метод Dispose, нужен для того, чтобы те, кто использует класс знали, что после окончания работы с объектом необходимо вызвать метод Dispose (или обернуть код в using). Таким образом, если класс реализует интерфейс IDisposable, то потребители сразу знают, что класс для своей работы использует какие-то ресурсы, которые необходимо освобождать. Более того, разработчики этого класса сами позаботились об освобождении и код, ответственный за это, поместили в метод Dispose.