# Правильная реализация Dispose

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть такой вопрос. Допустим, у меня есть класс, реализующий интерфейс IDisposable. У этого класса есть какой-то управляемый ресурс, который тоже реализует этот интерфейс. Вот минимальный код моего класса.

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private SomeContext _context = new SomeContext();

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        if(_context != null)    
            _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

И тут у меня возник вопрос. Насколько правильна эта реализация? Точнее насколько она неправильна и чем это грозит? (везде где смотрел я видел более сложную реализацию Dispose паттерна). Вроде бы имеется всего одно IDisposable поле (предполагается что оно корректно реализует этот паттерн в своих внутренностях), и чтобы освободить ресурс корректно, достаточно просто в нужное время вызвать метод Dispose для поля _context. В чем я не прав? Применима ли такая простая реализация на практикке и чем она вообще плоха?

Comment: Сейчас найду дубликат :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105

Comment: @VladD, а чего не бамкнул?

Comment: @Grundy, это разве вопросы. Там про сам IDisposable, а тут - про конкретную реализацию.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а разве в более общем вопросе нет ответа на конкретный? :)

Comment: [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) из Framework Design Guidelines (обязательно к прочтению полностью).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, в этой схеме всё верно. Неуправляемых ресурсов нет, финализатор не нужен. Dispose вызов прокидывает дальше, т. е. своё дело делает.

А вообще, рекомендую почитать: http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2011/09/dispose-pattern.html, особенно раздел *Упрощенная версия Dispose паттерна,* который очень похож на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 9):

Всё правильно, но можно убрать проверку на `null`.

Если класс сконструировался, то `_context` не равно `null`, т. к. `new` не может вернуть `null`.

Итого:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    SomeContext _context = new SomeContext();    
    public void Dispose() => _context.Dispose();
}
```

---

Обратите внимание, иногда уместно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    bool isDisposed = false;
    void EnsureSelfAlive()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException();
    }

    SomeContext _context = new SomeContext();    

    public void Dispose()
    {
        isDisposed = true;
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

и в каждом публичном методе в начале вызывать `EnsureSelfAlive()`. Позволяет отлавливать какое-то количество ошибок.

Проверять `isDisposed` в `Dispose` не нужно, т. к. `_context` должен уметь «пережить» множественные вызовы `_context.Dispose()`.

Comment: почему? а если кто-то где-то присвоит значение null? :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну это если :) В текущем коде не нужно.

Comment: Эм.. а если там исключение в самом `new SomeContext()`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Тогда исключение улетит вверх, оно ж нигде не перехватывается, и не сконструируется основновной класс

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тогда на объекты `SomeContext` и `MyClass` не будет ни у кого ссылки, и никто не сможет вызвать на них `Dispose`.

Comment: @VladD, кроме финализатора. Но его тут нет, так что, пожалуй, да.

Comment: `EnsureSelfAlive` - по идее, при необходимости исключение сам `_context` бросит. Так что, штука в некоторых случаях полезная, но абсолютно не критичная.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, нужно в том случае, если есть работа с внутренними штуками без обращения к `_context`.

Comment: @VladD, и мы хотим дать понять пользователю, что нас уже уничтожили. Но, до тех пор, пока у нас нет unmanaged-ресурсов, которые мы освободили, мы без вреда для окружающих можем отдавать любые свои данные. Т. е. в таком случае исключение - это скорее некий семантический бонус, но никак не функционально-необходимая деталь. Так?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Главное — конечно, семантический бонус. Но ещё например мы можем уже закрыть нужный файл, или отписаться от какого-то ивента или что-то ещё, и быть в нерабочем состоянии. Ну или просто разрушить внутренний инвариант. В этой ситуации мы просто не можем продолжать работать, и надо бы кинуть правильное исключение, а не крешнуться по NullReferenceException.