# Следует ли использовать SuppressFinalize?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора, clr

Хотел бы спросить про такой паттерн использования `SuppressFinalize`. Допустим, у меня имеется объект `Foo`, который хранит в себе какой-нибудь ресурс. Объект `Foo` ответственен за освобождение выделенного ресурса. Я использую всегда такой подход:

Класс `Foo` всегда реализует `finalize` и `dispose` методы, которые используют внутренний метод, который освобождает ресурсы. При вызове `dispose` я всегда вызываю `SuppressFinalize` метод (дабы оптимизировать процесс сборки мусора - не нужно будет хранить данный объект в очереди финализации, ну или например если я забуду явно вызвать `dispose` метод).

Имеет ли данный подход какие-либо `performance` недостатки? Не могу понять, будет ли иметь какие-либо "сайд эффекты" такой подход - например что `gc` всегда подобные объекты будет помещать в очередь финализации

UPDATE: Пример использования (написан на C++/Cli - флажок в `CleanResources` не используется потому что управляемых полей нет) И еще, я упростил немного код, вызов нативных методов обрамлен try/catch блоком, дабы оборачивать исключения в свой управляемый тип исключения

```
NativeWrapper::NativeWrapper(void) :
   m_native(new Native())
{
}

NativeWrapper::~NativeWrapper(void)
{
    CleanResources();
    System::GC::SuppressFinalize(this);
}

NativeWrapper::!NativeWrapper(void)
{
CleanResources();
}

void NativeWrapper::CleanResources(void)
{
    delete m_native;
}
```

Comment: Имеет смысл хранить ресурс в управляемой обёртке типа `SafeHandle` и не заморачиваться с корректной имплементацией `IDisposable` с неуправляемыми ресурсами (которая очень сложна). Читайте [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105).

Comment: @VladD, насколько я правильно понимаю, SafeHandle имеет смысл только для WinApi ресурсов использовать. А что если я использую память выделенную из неуправляемого кода? Тогда все как раз сводится к моей реализации?

Comment: А как именно вы её аллоцируете?

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос (вставил код)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не вижу недостатков в смысле производительности. Единственный недостаток — `IDisposable` должен быть идемпотентен, то есть должно быть возможно вызвать `Dispose` дважды. У вас это на текущий момент приведёт к двойному освобождению памяти, так что имеет смысл завести ещё и флаг `isDisposed`.

Даже если *вы* в вашем коде пользуетесь `using`, всё равно клиент может в любой момент вызвать [`GC.ReRegisterForFinalize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.reregisterforfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx), что приведёт к вызову `Finalize` даже после `Dispose`.

(Большой обзор, посвящённый реализации `IDisposable`, включающий заготовку для кастомной обёртки, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486697/10105).)

Comment: Очень хорошее замечание, я это пропустил. Можно еще просто занулить `m_native`. Правда потом осторожно отслеживать использование этого нативного ресурса (чтобы метод у null не вызвать). А вообще я правильно понимаю, финализатор это просто лишняя страховка? допустим если забыли явно вызвать диспоз

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать код! Очень хорошая ссылка

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Возможно, в конец _конструктора_ имеет смысл вставить `GC.KeepAlive(this);` ещё. Но тут включаются тонкие вопросы многопоточности.

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Пожалуйста!

Comment: а что вы имели ввиду под словом `using` в моем коде? не понял этот момент.

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Ну, если ваш объект используется из C#-кода при помощи конструкции `using (var w = new NativeWrapper()) { /*сделать что-то с ним*/ }`. В этом случае гарантирован вызов `Dispose` (то есть, `~NativeWrapper()`), но при этом, несмотря на `SuppressFinalize`, финализатор (`!NativeWrapper()`) тоже может быть вызван.

Comment: Ага, понял что вы имели ввиду