# Правильное переопределение Dispose(bool disposing)?

Tags: c#

Имеется класс, реализующий паттерн **Disposable**:

```
    internal class SomeDisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly System.IO.Stream _managedResource;

        private bool _disposed;

        public SomeDisposableClass(System.IO.Stream managedResource)
        {
            _managedResource = managedResource;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(disposing)
            {
                _managedResource?.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

А есть класс, *наследующийся* от него:

```
    internal sealed class DerivedDisposableClass : SomeDisposableClass
    {
        private readonly System.IO.Stream _anotherResource;

        public DerivedDisposableClass(System.IO.Stream managedResource, System.IO.Stream anotherResource) 
            : base(managedResource)
        {
            _anotherResource = anotherResource;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _anotherResource?.Dispose();

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос:** Нужно ли в классе-наследнике вводить флаг `_disposed`? Если да, то какой от этого профит?

**И ещё:** Может кто-нибудь на пальцах объяснить, какова польза от `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` в классе-родителе (при условии, что наследник будет иметь финализатор)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Флаг `_disposed` в вашем варианте наследнику **нужен** потому что как ему иначе определить что его уже нет?

Чтобы не заводить отдельный флаг на каждого наследника - можно немного изменить родителя.

Вариант 1. Вынесите проверку флага наружу, в невиртуальный `Dispose()`. В таком случае наследник будет просто знать что переопределенный `Dispose(bool)` будет вызван только один раз и проверка будет не нужна.

Вариант 2. Сделайте защищенное (protected) свойство `IsDisposed` в базовом классе.

От `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` большая польза - он отменяет финализатор, что позволяет сборщику мусора собрать ваш объект за одну попытку а не за две.

---

Тем не менее, полный паттерн Disposable давно уже устарел. Гораздо красивее выглядит альтернативный подход, при котором считается недопустимым владение одновременно и управляемым и неуправляемым ресурсом в одном классе.

Недостатки классического паттерна Disposable:

1. он создает избыточную нагрузку на память потому что "тяжелые" объекты с финализаторами не могут быть собраны GC пока финализатор не отработает или не будет отменен;
2. он вызывает утечку ресурсов при выгрузке домена приложений (а это частое явление в том же ASP.NET).

Согласно более современному подходу, обычные классы в принципе не могут владеть неуправляемыми ресурсами - а потому им не нужен ни финализатор, ни метод `Dispose(bool)`.

Для неуправляемых же ресурсов полагается делать управляемые обертки, желательно - на основе `SafeHandle`, но можно и на основе `CriticalFinalizerObject`.

Более подробно этот подход расписал VladD в вопросе [Как и когда нужно имплементировать IDisposable?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105)

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, ваша имплементация *неверна*: вы не должны работать с управляемыми ресурсами в финализаторе. Соответственно вам нужно

```
if(disposing)
{
    _anotherResource?.Dispose();
}
```

Флаг `_disposed` имеет смысл вводить, если он не доступен из базового класса. Если флаг доступен из базового класса, по идее можно его и не перекрывать.

Флаг понадобится вам для того, чтобы бросить исключение, если публичный метод будет вызван на уже `Dispose`-нутом объекте. А также для того, чтобы сделать ваш метод `Dispose` *повторяемым*: два вызова `Dispose` подряд не должны приводить к падению, и должны быть равносильны одному. (В принципе, часто для этой цели можно обойтись и без флага, да.)

По поводу `SuppressFinalize` смотрите ответ @Pavel Mayorov. (А также обязательно прочитайте вторую часть ответа, под чертой.)