# Правильная очистка памяти

Tags: c#, .net

Как правильно реализовать очистку памяти?
Посмотрел примеры: [docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx), [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/8.2.php).

Но нигде не показано, что делать с объектами внутри класса...

Например вот часть класса таблицы:

```
   #region fields

    private List<Module> _allModule;

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    public ModuleTable(List<Module> allModule)
    {
        _allModule = allModule;
    }

    #endregion
```

Как правильно реализовать очистку памяти для такого класса с применением интерфейсов `IDisposable`?

Comment: А зачем вам это? Вы хотите в определённый момент времени очистить память?

Comment: Ещё, конкретно в том коде что вы привели, всё само без труда очистится, никаких самописных деструкторов не нужно. Ровно по этому, в учебниках по шарпу и не пишут деструкторы в таких случаях.

Comment: @test123 да, есть три различные таблицы, которые необходимы только в тот момент, когда пользователь загружает данные из системы (в них хранится пояснения понятные человеку). После загрузки они становятся не нужны и при этом занимают приличный объем. Да и в целом хочу понять как проводить очистку.

Comment: Тогда вы только можете намекнуть GC на то что не используете объект. (например, очистить список, либо сослаться на null) Если вам нужно управлять памятью - вы выбрали не тот язык.

Comment: @test123 а могли бы подсказать все таки вариант как это делается? (можно не для конкретного класса). Просто на всех сайтах/книгах одно и тоже описание, а конкретики никакой.

Comment: В шарпе вы не оперируете памятью. Ей оперирует GC. Поэтому никто и не говорит об очистке. Вы всё перекладываете со своих плеч на GC. Если же возникла ситуация, в которой необходимо конкретно в текущий момент времени быстро очистить память - нужно извращаться и прибегать к хитростям. Но, даже они, не могут гарантировать что вы сможете очистить память тогда когда вам нужно. (хотя, политика NET, сдесь более щадящая, нежели java, и можно принудительно вежливо попросить GC выполнить чистку)

Comment: @test123 это с применением GC.Collect()?

Comment: Да, именно с ним. предварительно обнулив все поля, которые хотите "забыть".

Comment: @test123 спасибо, буду пробовать написать, все идет к тому, что пора покупать книгу clr Рихтера...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В .NET есть два вида памяти — управляемая и неуправляемая.

Явное освобождение управляемой памяти практически никогда не нужно, главное, чтобы на неё не было ссылок из «корневых» объектов. При этом её при недостатке памяти съест сборщик мусора.

Важные случаи, когда необходимо «вручную» заботиться об освобождении управляемой памяти: вы подписываетесь на событие у долгоживущего объекта, при этом у объекта есть неявно ссылка на ваш объект, а значит, ваш объект не будет убран сборщиком мусора. Методы борьбы с этим — отписка от события в момент, когда она больше не нужна, или использование `WeakEventManager`.

---

Неуправляемую память нужно оборачивать в объект, реализующий `IDisposable` (например, `SafeHandle`). Когда она не нужна, ещё нужно освободить при помощи `Dispose`. (Об этом в деталях [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105).) Впрочем, освобождать `IDisposable` нужно и если за ними нет неуправляемой памяти.

---

Конкретно для вашего случая, у вас не видно ни подписок на события, ни других методов попасть в глобальные списки. Если ваш `Module` реализует `IDisposable` и вы — владелец объектов, то вы должны в нужный момент вызвать `Dispose`. Иначе по идее ничего делать не надо, разве что обнулите ссылку на ваш объект из долгоживущего объекта и ждите, пока объект съестся сборщиком мусора.

Comment: рад вас видеть)
а можно пример реализации dispoce? во всех примерах написано что-то типа "тут что-то делаем"

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105

Comment: спасибо! Вам стоит книги писать!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Эх, было бы на это время...

Comment: @VladD имхо вам можно просто сборник ваших ответов на SO выпустить, и бестселлер готов :)

Comment: @tym32167: (_покраснел_)

Comment: @tym32167 Я бы приобрёл такую книжечку хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Вот вам покамест электронный вариант: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd?tab=answers&sort=votes

Comment: @VladD Да я итак сей электронный вариант листаю почти регулярно перед сном)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: (_ещё больше покраснел_)