# .NET Как побороть 2й вызов финализатора

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Не могу побороть, даже не побороть, а отловить когда происходит 2й вызов финализатора объекта. Все 3 объекта, должны быть уничтожены в определенном порядке, если это произойдет в произвольном порядке, то возможны либо утечки памяти, либо уничтожение статического неуправляемого объекта который отвечает за работоспособность 3х представленных объектов

Создание объектов:

1. VlcInstance
2. VlcMediaPlayer / VlcMedia
3. VlcMedia / VlcMediaPlayer

---

Уничтожение:

1. VlcMedia
2. VlcMediaPlayer
3. VlcInstance

> В случае удаления функции финализаторов объектов, и использованием
>   исключительно деструктора, все классы работают именно так как нужно.

Если возможно то подскажите где в данном коде вызываются финализаторы, за исключением выхода из `Main`

Код c# который управляет объектами:

```
using System;

namespace libvlc.net.test.csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static VlcInstance vlcInstance;
        static VlcMediaPlayer vlcPlayer;
        static VlcMedia vlcMedia;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine("..\\..\\libvlc-data\\2.2.6\\bin\\", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "x86\\" : "x64");

            vlcInstance = new VlcInstance(path, "-I", "logger,none", "-vv", "--no-plugins-cache", "--ignore-config");
            vlcPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(vlcInstance);
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            while(((cki = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape))
            {
                switch (cki.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
                        vlcPlayer.TooglePause();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        vlcPlayer.Stop();
                        if (!(vlcMedia is null))
                        {
                            vlcMedia.MediaEvent -= VlcMedia_MediaEvent;
                            vlcMedia.Dispose();
                        }
                        vlcMedia = new VlcMedia(vlcInstance,
                            new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isyami/libvlc.net/master/", "test2")));
                        vlcMedia.MediaEvent += VlcMedia_MediaEvent;
                        vlcPlayer.Open(vlcMedia);
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        vlcPlayer.Stop();
                        if (!(vlcMedia is null))
                        {
                            vlcMedia.MediaEvent -= VlcMedia_MediaEvent;
                            vlcMedia.Dispose();
                        }
                        vlcMedia = new VlcMedia(vlcInstance,
                            new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isyami/libvlc.net/master/", "test")));
                        vlcMedia.MediaEvent += VlcMedia_MediaEvent;
                        vlcPlayer.Open(vlcMedia);
                        break;
                }
            }

            vlcMedia = null;
            vlcPlayer = null;
            vlcInstance = null;
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private static void VlcMedia_MediaEvent(object s, VlcMediaEventArgs a)
        {
            switch (a.EventType)
            {
                case VlcMediaEvent.MetaChanged:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: \t\t{a.EventData.NewMeta}");
                    break;
                case VlcMediaEvent.SubItemAdded:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: NewSubItem");
                    break;
                case VlcMediaEvent.DurationChanged:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: \t{a.EventData.NewDuration}");
                    break;
                case VlcMediaEvent.ParsedChanged:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: \t\t{a.EventData.NewParsed}");
                    break;
                case VlcMediaEvent.Freed:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: \t\tMediaFreed");
                    break;
                case VlcMediaEvent.StateChanged:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a.EventType}: \t\t{a.EventData.NewState}");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К чему в конце функции Main вызовы GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers и
GC.Collect, причем именно в таком порядке? Запускать сборку мусора перед выходом из программы бессмысленно, а финализаторы CLR и так автоматически запускает при завершении процесса

Comment: Зачем снесли ответ? Вызывать SuppressFinalize в Dispose действительно нужно (так рекомендует и документация, и заплюсованный ответ в связанном вопросе). Понятия не имею, почему его заминусовали.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Ну те кто не читал документацию и заминусовали =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Финализаторы вызываются фоновым потоком финализации, в какой угодно момент и в произвольном порядке, только бы на объекты не было ссылок.

Ваш код не должен зависеть от порядка финализаторов, потому что он не гарантирован. Хуже того, вы не имеете права работать с управляемыми полями ваших объектов в финализаторе, т. к. они могут быть уже финализированы.

Если вам нужно контролировать удаление объектов, вам стоит воспользоваться интерфейсом `IDisposable`. Вам придётся менять дизайн. Сорри.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересно это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105

Comment: Как же у меня руки начинают опускаться когда до такого доходит в .NET, что я не могу сам освободить память так как необходимо.

Comment: @Yami: Так вы всё же посмотрите в сторону `IDisposable`. Оно специально для этого и придумано.