# Является ли Finalize деструктором?

Tags: c#

Является ли Finalize деструктором?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Деструктор - многозначное слово, в каждом языке он означает что-то свое.

С точки зрения спецификации языка C#, никакого метода Finalize нет. Есть только деструкторы, которые вызываются сборщиком мусора. Однако известные компиляторы преобразуют деструктор в метод Finalize, таким образом Finalize - это реализация языковой конструкции "деструктор".

С точки зрения языка С++, деструктор - это место где детерминированно освобождаются ресурсы. На роль такого деструктора больше подходит не Finalize, а метод Dispose. Это отражено в языке C++/CLI, где конструкция `~classname()` преобразуется компилятором именно в Dispose, а для Finalize введена новая конструкция `!classname()`

С точки зрения языка Delphi в его неуправляемой версии, деструктор - это метод который освобождает память выделенную под объект. Такого деструктора в C# существовать не может.

Comment: Спасибо,а что такое Dispose,и как им пользоваться

Comment: @ЛаврикКан https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: @ЛаврикКан https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/218063

Comment: А что лучше использовать Finalize или IDisposable

Comment: @ЛаврикКан от задачи зависит. Вы все-таки прочитайте ответ по ссылке, которую вам дал Андрей.

Comment: Извините я не дописал,для неуправляемых ресурсов что лучше использовать Finalize или IDisposable ?

Comment: @ЛаврикКан оба метода, а еще лучше - SafeHandle. Вы все-таки почитайте что написано по той ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

У деструктора, строго говоря, определенная запись - это именно `~className() {}`.  А `finalize` - это часть внутренней инфраструктуры - и он неявно вызывается деструктором, причем когда и где выполнится `finalize` - не определено, т.е. решает рантайм и никак это нельзя контролировать. Для четкого контроля уничтожения ресурсов объекта следует реализовывать интерфейс `IDisposable`. И вообще все это не следует применять если у вас нет неуправляемых ресурсов - смысл теряется, а процессорное время тратится.

Comment: На самом деле компилятор превращает `~Classname() { ... }` в `protected override void Finalize() { ...; base.Finalize(); }`

Comment: Иными словами, на самом деле Finalize вызывает деструктор, а вовсе не наоборот.

Comment: Соглсаен с вашими поправками, но все же ответ от этого принципиально не меняется - деструктор и финалайз - не одно и тоже хоть и связаны.

Comment: А что лучше использовать Finalize или IDisposable

Comment: `IDisposable` - позволяет вам самим контролировать когда и где вызывать. Явное лучше неявного. На мой взгляд.