# Долгоживущие объекты и CoTaskMemAlloc C++ vs C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshal

Тут задался теоритеческим вопросом, какова судьба переменной в С++ коде когда память для нее выделялась `CoTaskMemAlloc`?

Схема примерно такая:

C++ выделяем память переменной через CoTaskMemAlloc, отдаем переменную в C# управляемый код.

В C# коде, переменная описана как возвращаемая с наружи:

`[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`.

Далее, уборщик мусора в C# теоретически должен освободить память этой переменной, когда решит что она более не нужна, но когда он это сделает (и сделает ли) не очевидно.

Так вот в чем вопрос, как в C++ коде понять, освобождена ли память присвоенная этой переменной или ещё нет? Null ей явно присвоен не будет, если я правильно понимаю..

И как я догадываюсь вызывать "возможно вторично" `CoTaskMemFree` из C++ кода не безопасно.

К сожалению про логику работы связки `CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree` в разных ситуациях на msdn написано чуть меньше чем ничего..

Comment: С каких пор сборщик мусора стал собирать неуправляемую память? А так, для заметки, если вы подключаете библиотеку и выделяете память в ней, то именна эта библиотека должна освободить память.

Comment: С тех пор как Маршалинг использует CoTaskMemFree для очистки памяти, то есть очень давно :) в этом и есть смысл описание return параметра в C#

Comment: @LLENN, в том то и смысл использовать Com-Ole аллокатор, чтоб развязать ситуацию с очисткой памяти в том же месте где и выделялась.

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы после освобождения памяти указатель на ячейку памяти обнулялся после освобождения памяти, напишите кастомный маршаллер, других вариантов думаю нет.

Comment: Ну это совсем не трудно, я так понимаю.. есть ли примеры? Все что связано с маршалингом весьма объемное по коду, правда я давно в исходники смотрел (Моно)

Comment: Если это поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890207/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80

Comment: Спасибо, полезно