# LiberOffice после использования не выключает свои процессы

Tags: c#, .net, open-office, libre-office

Использую библиотеки LiberOffice для создания и работы с документом (Замена текста), все работает, но при окончании работ в процессах остаются висеть два процесса Либры, а именно: soffice.exe и soffice.bin.

- Их расположение: C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program

Проблема заключается в том, что когда эти процессы висят - не получается открыть оснастку (саму либру), начинает мигать(Появляться/исчезать 3 раза в секунду) баннер запуска LiberOffice. Но если процессы явно выключить(убить) то Либра спокойно запускается. Аналогична обратная вторая проблема, когда на устройстве включен LiberOffice - программная функция по работе с документами LiberOffice не срабатывает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода, подключение:

```
private XMultiServiceFactory connect()
    {
        var componentContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
        return (XMultiServiceFactory) componentContext.getServiceManager();
    }
```

Получить документ по адресу:

```
private unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument initDocumentCreate(unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory factory)
    {
        try
        {
            XComponentLoader loader = (XComponentLoader)
                factory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
            
            var urlPath = "Тут урл до файла odt";
            
            XComponent component = loader.loadComponentFromURL(
                urlPath, "_default", 0,
                new unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[0]);
            
            return (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument) component;
        }
        catch {
            throw new System.Exception("Сообщение об ошибке");
        }
        
    }
```

Работа с документом:

```
{
        try
        {
            var factory = connect();
            var document = initDocument(factory);
            /*Код-код-код*/
            CloseLibraProc(document);
            /*Код-код-код*/
            return doc;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Вот так обрабатываю закрытие:

```
private void CloseLibraProc(unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument document)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = (XStorable) document;
            store.store();
            
            var close = (unoidl.com.sun.star.util.XCloseable) document;
            
            if (close != null )
                close.close(false);
            else
            {
                var component = (XComponent) document;
                component.dispose();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Ошибка при закрытии или сохранении");
        }
    }
```

Возможно функция закрытия не совсем корректная и чего-то не хватает?

Comment: `SuppressFinalize(this)` а это зачем? Такая штука может быть только внутри метода `Dispose()` при реализации `IDisposable` интерфейса. Код с использованием `var` не могу прочесть. Можете исправить на явные типы?

Comment: [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @aepot GC.Collect() и
GC.SuppressFinalize(this) собирает мусор, без него последовательное включение функции не работает, так как пишет что документ уже открыт

Comment: Тогда вместо `SuppressFinalize` надо `WaitForPendingFinalizers`, но все равно это выглядит как костыль, чтобы заткнуть какую-то ошибку в коде.

Comment: @aepot `WaitForPendingFinalizers` пробывали - не помогло, в некоторых примерах видели, по работе с либрой, что используют именно его `SuppressFinalize`

Comment: Оно ничего не делает, только сообщает сборщику о том, что не надо вызывать финализатор текущего объекта, когда объект будет собираться. Разберитесь, как это работает. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138718/373567), который может помочь разобраться со сборщиком.

Comment: А вообще, ваш вопрос не понятен, 4 неизвестно как взаимодействующих куска кода. Нужен воспроизводимый пример, чтобы я или кто-то другой мог взять ваш код и протестировать. Сейчас ваш код опубликован в таком состоянии, что он даже не скомпилируется. Что за библиотеку для интеграции с офисом используете, где ее взять? Или вы расчитываете получить помощь от тех, кто использует либру? Так вот, здесь скорее всего таких нет, поэтому лучше оформите вопрос в соответствии с этим обстоятельством.