# GC и инициализация объекта в аргументах метода

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Есть вот такой пример кода:

```
public void DoActions(UserClass MyClass)
{
    //Actions with MyClass
}
```

Как поведет себя GC если я проинициализирую `UserClass` прямо в аргументах метода? Т.е. :

```
DoActions(new UserClass());
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что GC "подчистит" объект при выходе из метода/при очередной сборке мусора? А если объект будет содержать управляемый ресурс из внешней библиотеки? Достаточно ли будет реализации в `UserClass` метода `Dispose` и деконструктора для очистки этого ресурса? Т.е. например вот так:

```
public class UserClass : IDisposable
{
    public ClassFromExtendLibrary Memory; //Например какой-нибудь класс из внешней библиотеки реализующий внутри интерфейс IDisposable
    public int[] SomeArray;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    //some code

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(_disposed) return;
        if(disposing)
        {
            SomeArray = null;
            Memory?.Dispose();
        }
        
        _disposed = true;
    }
    ~UserClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Почти правильно. `UMemory?.Dispose();` можно вызывать только если `disposing = true`. Правило: finaliser не трогает объекты .NET.  Возникает вопрос: а что тогда вообще может делать finaliser? Освобождать native resources, например `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Comment: Кстати, `SomeArray = null` в  `Dispose` - это лишнее, GC сам разберется с неуправляемыми объектами.

Comment: Нашёл ещё хорошее объяснение здесь  [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/89720/)  и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/129283/)

Comment: @AlexF Благодарю за ответы. А как вызовется метод `Dispose` у внутреннего управляемого объекта `Memory`, если я не вызову `Dispose` у `MyClass` в методе `DoActions`, ведь финализатор его не вызовет.

Comment: @AlexF Лучший вариант тогда вообще не делать инициализацию `UserClass` в аргументах метода `DoActions()`?

Comment: В тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138718/373567

Comment: Если вы не вызываете `Memory?.Dispose();`, то `Memory` освободит свои ресурсы только в своем финализаторе. А это произойдет через некторое время, когда GC решит. То есть, вместо очистки ресурсов немедленно и синхронно (Dispose) вы получите очистку "через какое-то время".  Все это при условии, что класс `Memory` реализован правильно.

Comment: Теперь понял - `Memory` (при правильной реализации) внутри имеет неуправляемый ресурс(`IntPtr`) и финализатор - который и будет во внутреннем методе `Dispose` освобождать этот ресурс. А GC(после выхода из метода `DoActions`) уже сам решит когда вызвать финализатор у `Memory`. Благодарю @AlexF c;

Answer (score 2):

> GC "подчистит" объект при выходе из метода?

Нет, GC не триггерится при входе в метод или выходе из метода.

> GC "подчистит" объект при очередной сборке мусора?

Опять же, нет. Если ссылка на объект ещё достижима, то он не будет собран.

А вот когда после выхода из метода объект станет недостижим и произойдёт сборка мусора, тогда он и будет собран.

> А если объект будет содержать управляемый ресурс из внешней библиотеки? Достаточно ли будет реализации в UserClass метода Dispose и деконструктора для очистки этого ресурса?

Управляемый ресурс не нуждается в паттерне IDisposable. Он полностью подвластен сборщику мусора.

А вот **не**управляемый ресурс нуждается в ручной очистке в финализаторе и/или методе Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

> GC "подчистит" объект при выходе из метода/при очередной сборке мусора

Да, но когда именно вызовется `GC` и вызовется ли он вообще за время работы программы - неизвестно, нет никаких гарантий его вызова.

> А если объект будет содержать управляемый ресурс из внешней библиотеки?

`Dispose` нужно вызывать в явном виде и лучше, конечно, с помощью `using` (есть два варианта - со скобками и без). Автоматически он не работает.

Comment: `Dispose нужно вызывать в явном виде и лучше` не то, чтобы нужно, просто очень рекомендуется, если ресурс хочется освободить как можно раньше. Если все равно, когда ресурс освободится - можно это и GC доверить (главное правильно реализовать паттерн - с финализатором), но это не рекомендуемый вариант.