# Пример очистки управляемого и неуправляемого ресурса

Tags: c#, .net

Читаю про паттерн `Dispose` и во всех примерах это выглядит так

- Очищаем управляемый ресурс
- Очищаем неуправляемый ресурс

из за этого складывается недопонимание.

Если к примеру `FileStream fS = new FileStream(path);` считается управляемым ресурсом, то в блоке, где очищаем управляемый ресурс, мы должны написать `fS.Close();`.

А какой пример можно привести для блока, который очищает неуправляемый ресурс?

Comment: Так смотря что за ресурс. Например, вы создали "вручную" временный файл, для очищения вы его должны удалить.

Comment: так это же можно назвать управляемым ресурсом

Comment: просто задайте себе вопрос - управляемый кем? Наверное, если вы создаете временный файл, то никто, кроме вас, его не будет удялять. Или если вы какой то COM компонент создаете, то его тоже сборщик мусора не уничтожит, надо уничтожать самому. Но если вы просто открываете файл на чтение, то его в какой то момент закроет сборщик, если вы сами его не закроете.

Comment: Неуправляемые ресурсы - это зачастую либо выделенная неуправляемая память, либо объекты взаимодействия с нативными библиотеками (указатели), например Win API. Внутри того же FileStream живет неуправляемый указатель на объект открытого файла в операционной системе, поэтому он IDisposable.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105

Answer (score 1):

Неуправляемый ресурс - это такой ресурс, который не контролируется CLR. То есть занимаемая им память не будет освобождена по средствам сборщика мусора. IDisposable - это интерфейс неуправляемых ресурсов, который реализует единственный метод Dispose(), который и отвечает за освобождение памяти. Однако за то, где этот метод будет вызван отвечает разработчик. Очевидно, что если его не вызвать, то объект будет висеть в памяти как минимум до конца работы вашей программы, а в некоторых случаях и после.

FileStream - тоже является неуправляемым ресурсом. Это нам подсказывает сигнатура родительского класса
`public abstract class Stream : MarshalByRefObject, IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable`

Когда вы вызываете .Close вы освобождаете память, потому что метод Close в том числе вызывает Dispose внутри себя.

Если неуправляемый ресурс нужен только в рамках выполнения метода, то может быть удобнее использовать using конструкцию, вместо того чтобы вызывать ручками .Dispose или .Close (для FileStream).

Проблемы начинаются, когда вам нужно использовать IDisposable объекты агрегированы в другие объекты. И когда вы уничтожаете объект, который содержит в себе IDisposable объект, вам нужно позаботиться об освобождении ресурсов лично. Для этого мелкомягкие предлагают использовать соответствующий паттерн:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose